# .clearfix class vs :after

Tags: css

Which is better when floating elements to left right?

Using a generic .clearfix class:

```
.clearfix:after{
  content:".";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  visibility:hidden;
  line-height:0;
  height:0;
}
```

which you can re-use and apply it to container elements:

```
   <div class="some-section clearfix">
     <div class="align-left"> left </div>
     <div class="align-right"> right </div>
   </div>

   <div class="some-other-section clearfix">
     <div class="align-right"> right </div>
   </div>
```

or specific clearing rules like:

```
.some-section:after, some-other-section:after{
  content:".";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  visibility:hidden;
  line-height:0;
  height:0;
}
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which method of 'clearfix' is best?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Comment: @WesleyMurch not so much. The OP is asking how to apply the rules, not which rules to apply.

Comment: @steveax: No, the OP is asking which one is "better". "how to apply the rules" is already in her post.

Comment: @WesleyMurch note: the style rules in both of the code blocks are identical. The only difference is whether to apply them via a `clearfix` class or include the rules directly to all elements that need clearing.

Comment: @steveax: You're correct, the title misled me - but the link should still be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the use of `:after`, one must considered the cross-browser issue. If we are to provide support for all browsers, including old ones, pseudo-elements may not be the way:

[CSS selectors and pseudo selectors browser compatibility](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/)

---

Related to **generic class** *vs* **specific class**

**By definition:**

A **generic class** can be applied to any element in the markup, is best suited for use with generic formatting instructions that all elements will support, or for formatting instructions that need to be used on several types of element.

A **specific class** serves its purpose by only being applied to a specific element in the markup is best suited for formatting instructions which are specific to only one type of element.

**The goals for using a Generic Class over a Specific one are:** <sup>among others</sup>

1. Cleaner markup
2. Reutilization
3. Smaller files (browser contents download performance)
4. Easy to maintain or update

Comment: the only problem with the generic class is that it imposes some limitations to the markup. for example, if I'd want to change alignment of some elements than I'd have to remove the clearfix class from the markup too...

Comment: I deal with that issue by combining generic classes! e.g. `<div class="clearfix alignL">Foo bar</div>` tells the browser that what is defined on `alignL` will have priority over the same declarations at `clearfix`! So, no need to remove, just set them by relevance!

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer .clearfix since it has the most browser support - IE6&7 don't support :after selector. In addition, you can define clearing properties in one place and add the class anywhere you need to use them. If you keep using :after on per-element basis, you'll end with a lot of duplicated CSS.

Comment: The OP is asking whether to add a `clearfix` class to all elements that need it or to apply the same style rules to every class/id that need it - in either event, the style rules applied are identical. I prefer to use a CSS meta-language (Sass) and use `@include` so I don't have to sprinkle non-semantic classes in the html _and_ the clearing rules are in only one place.

Comment: @steveax, thank you for reiterating what the OP wanted to know. From my experience with includes, unless styles are one or two lines long, you end up with a lot duplicated code and a bloated css file. There are times and places where "non-semantic" classes are appropriate and useful.

Answer (score 1):

Neither, really. Internet Explorer 7 and earlier don't support pseudo-elements, so here's what I use:

```css
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

and

```
<br class="clearfix" />
```

It's nearly semantic, works even in IE 6, and is really nice and clean.

Comment: There are other CSS methods for clearfix that don't involve rubbish markup or pseudo elements: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1633170/398242 *"Really nice and clean"*? Far from it! *"nearly semantic"* - makes no sense!

Comment: IE6/7 have an auto-clearing bug with floated elements that renders clearfix unnecessary. The purpose of using the `:after` pseudo-class with `.clearfix` is to target only those browsers that don't auto-clear.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: I find it really nice and clean. *Much* cleaner than the answer you linked to.

Comment: @jaredhoyt: Not seeing that in IE 7.

Comment: @minitech: The answer I linked to contained the `<br>` trick, I think you didn't scroll down and see the variety of solutions. Most of the time `overflow:hidden` is fine, and works in IE7, but there is always a way to "clearfix" with only CSS. (`zoom:1`?) I don't have access to IE6 or care about optimizing for it at all anymore to be honest.